# adb tcp не видит устройства

Tags: android, adb

Хочу подключить телефон по вайфай на android studio. 
У меня 2 телефона lenovo p1 про и p780 . 
У p1 все отлично работает.
А у p780 adb подключает устройство, но не видит в команде devices.

```
#adb connect 192.168.0.155:5555
connected to 192.168.0.155:5555

#adb devices
List of devices attached
```

А если подключить другой телефон его видит и работает:

```
#adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.0.111:5555      device
```

Comment: А на телефоне точно  разрешен adb через wifi? Помниться мне, что раньше нужно было специально рутать телефон.

Comment: @KoVadim, У меня подобная проблема на SGN4 (Android 6.0.1) – adb over wi-fi вообще не работает, телефон пингуется, но не подключается. Где-то нужно отдельно включить «adb over wi-fi»?

Comment: я бы для начала поискал программу для этого в маркете, типа такой https://play.google.com/store/search?q=adb%20wifi&c=apps и попробовал включить (таких программ - вагон и тележка).

Comment: @KoVadim, Я их видел, но, почему-то у меня сложилось впечатление, что они только показывают IP-адрес устройства :)

Comment: @KoVadim, Ан нет, заработало, спасибо!

Comment: у меня рут есть) и программа тоже) но все равно не работает)